# Ajax não passa informações para servlet

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, input, servlet

Tenho um problema com o código, a servlet não é chamada. Só funciona se eu colocar action="FileUploader" no form. Há algum erro? tem alguma outra forma de fazer? O que eu preciso: um array de imagens, onde as imagens são recebidas em um único campo multiple/form data(ou seja, todas as imagens recebidas de uma vez) em que seja passado para a servlet, sem redirecionar a página. Agradeço desde já.

```
<form id="form1">    

    <label for="sampleText">Please enter a text</label>

    <input id="sampleText" name="sampleText" type="text" /> <br/>

    <label for="sampleFile">Please select a file

    <input id="sampleFile" name="sampleFile" type="file" /> <br/>

    <input id="uploadBtn" type="button" value="Ajax Submit" onClick="performAjaxSubmit();"></input>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function performAjaxSubmit() {

        var sampleText = document.getElementById("sampleText").value;

        var sampleFile = document.getElementById("sampleFile").files[0];

        var formdata = new FormData();

        formdata.append("sampleText", sampleText);

        formdata.append("sampleFile", sampleFile);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();       

        xhr.open("POST","FileUploader", true);

        xhr.send(formdata);

        xhr.onload = function(e) {

            if (this.status == 200) {

               alert(this.responseText);

            }

        };                    

    }   

</script>


public class FileUploader extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,

                          HttpServletResponse response)

                          throws ServletException, IOException {

        String ajaxUpdateResult = "";

        try {

            List items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);            

            for (FileItem item : items) {

                if (item.isFormField()) {

                    ajaxUpdateResult += "Field " + item.getFieldName() + 

                    " with value: " + item.getString() + " is successfully read\n\r";

                } else {

                    String fileName = item.getName();

                    InputStream content = item.getInputStream();

                    response.setContentType("text/plain");

                    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

                    // Do whatever with the content InputStream.

                    System.out.println(Streams.asString(content));

                    ajaxUpdateResult += "File " + fileName + " is successfully uploaded\n\r";

                }

            }

        } catch (FileUploadException e) {

            throw new ServletException("Parsing file upload failed.", e);

        }

        response.getWriter().print(ajaxUpdateResult);

    }
}
```